# Rail Query includes + filter by column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I start in Ruby and Ruby on rails. I am trying to modify the access to this object (below) in base via the form and I will like to filter by the values that are in the table node_tags.

```
def map
......
  nodes = Node.bbox(bbox).where(:visible => true).includes(:node_tags).limit(MAX_NUMBER_OF_NODES + 1)
.....
end
```

Probably on SQL request

```
SELECT * FROM nodes n INNER JOIN node_tags nt on  n.node_id = nt.node_id where nt.k = 'alert' and nt.v = 'true'
```

Table nodes

```
| node_id | latitude  | longitude | changeset_id | visible | timestamp | tile | version | redaction_id |
|---------|-----------|-----------|--------------|---------|-----------|------|---------|--------------|
|   11    | 473705641 |  3955487  |  11          |  TRUE   |
|   12    | 473705641 |  3955487  |  12          |  TRUE   |
```

table node_tags

```
| node_id |   k   |   v  | 
|---------|-------|------|
|  11     | name  | bob  |
|  12     | alert | true |
```

Comment: What is the problem? what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you need to get sql as in your example by ORM (ActiveRecord).
Try this:

```
nodes = Node.where(:visible => true).join(:node_tags).where("node_tags.k = 'alert' and node_tags.v = 'true'")
```